# Keyboard shortcut for replace and find next in textmate

Tags: shortcut, textmate

The <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> finds the next occurrence. <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> does NOT do the right thing: it brings up the Find/Replace dialog - and if you just hit <kbd>↩</kbd> it does not properly default to Replace and Find. I am NOT going to mouse over to manually click on it since this is a highly frequent activity.

So then what is the way to do the find/replace just with the keyboard?

Comment: I have dumped TextMate - and this was a leading cause.  Instead am enjoying MacVim.